# Why am I getting 1.#QNB when I do not return a value from a function returning double

Tags: c, function, return, double, return-value

I was writing a menu driven program in C. So when I call a function
I'm trying to understand how return works. So 
I wrote a code something like

```
double function_name(parameters){
    //some code here
if(condition here)
    return (x);
else
    return ;
}

int main( void ){
    //some code here
    double l = function_name(argument);
    printf("returns: %.4lf\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

When code goes into else then it prints

> Output: returns: 1.#QNB

What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Your function is supposed to return a `double` and you're not returning anything, so of course the result is Undefined Behaviour. (Also your compiler should be at least warning you about this, no ?)

Comment: No I'm not getting any _warnings  & errors_  @Paul R

Comment: (a) `1.#QNB` is just `1.#QNAN` (i.e. a "quiet" NaN) "rounded" to 4 decimal places - this is pretty much irrelevant though, since your code is exhibiting UB. (b) you don't say what compiler you are using, but `gcc -Wall ...` will give you a bunch of warnings for the above code, most notably: `warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void`.

Comment: I was doing this compilation in [Codeblocks](http://codeblocks.org/)

Comment: OK - read the manual or online help and see if you can work out how to enable warnings - it will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: :p Warnings and error thing is enabled as I'm getting all other warnings. maybe the specific compiler doesn't consider it as a warning as the basic library files are handling it I guess but anyways I'd tried the Internet for it but now I'm trying to use "QNaN" as a keyword search

Comment: You used the wrong format specifier: `lf` was added in C99 (which you are clearly not using, because omitting `main`'s return type is an error in C99). `%.4f` would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QNaN (is a Quiet Not-a-Number) is an NaN with the MSB of the fraction part set. A QNaN, as opposed to an SNaN (Signalling NaN) is allowed to continue through floating point operations without raising an exception.In this case as I don't found much info on it, I'm guessing is similar.

---

As I'm returning *NOTHING* from the function and storing in a *floating type number* which is yielding me a **1.#QNB**

Comment: This explains what happened on *your particular instance* , however in general the behaviour could be anything.